# nginx - allow GET for all and allow DELETE only for certain IP in the same location block

Tags: nginx, location

I'm struggling on setting up restrictions by request method in the nginx location block.
I want to allow GET for everyone, however I want to allow DELETE as well but for certain IP addresses / CIDR only. How can I achieve this?

I tried with this, but that seems do not work as expected:

```
location /data {

  if ($request_method !~ ^(DELETE|GET) {
     return 405;
  }

  limit_except GET {
     allow all;
  }

  allow 10.10.10.0/24;
  allow 127.0.0.1;
  deny all;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved it.
I misinterpreted limit_except directive.

This is what worked for me:

```
limit_except GET {
  allow 10.10.10.0/24;
  allow 127.0.0.1;
  deny all;
}
```

So, what this actually says is allow GET for all and limit access to other methods for all except for specified IPs.

Directive in if clause is ignored. Other methods are controlled by backend application.